# EF5 Model-First, DBContext code generation and derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm creating a EF5 entity model with the designer (VS2012), and used the EF5 DbContext generator as code generation item.

My model contains an entity deriving from another (not abstract).

So let's say the base entity is called BaseEntity, and the derived entity is DerivedEntity.

Now I see in the generated context class, that there is no

```
Public DbSet<DerivedEntity> DerivedEntities { get; set; }
```

defined.

Only

```
Public DbSet<BaseEntity> BaseEntities { get; set; }
```

is defined.

Is this normal ? And if yes, how do I query the derived entities in linq ?

I'm used to query like this:

```
using(var ctx = new EntityContainer)
{
var q = from e in ctx.DerivedEntities <-- but this is now not possible since it doesn't exist
select e;

return q.ToList();
}
```

Thanks for replying.

**EDIT:**

As requested, generated classes posted:

[image: Entity Model Designer diagram (subset)]

```
public partial class Scheduling
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }

public partial class TeamScheduling : Scheduling
    {
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AssignmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
        public virtual Assignment Assignment { get; set; }
    }


public partial class EntityContainer : DbContext
    {
        public EntityContainer()
            : base("name=EntityContainer")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AssignmentPreference> AssignmentPreferences { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Scheduling> Schedulings { get; set; }
    }
```

As you see, the EntityContainer class does not contain

```
public DbSet<TeamScheduling> TeamSchedulings { get; set; }
```

Comment: Could you show examples of you model classes please?

Comment: Maybe you could save the diagram of your model as image and post it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected when you use inheritance the way you have. `context.Schedulings` contains both `Scheduling` objects and `TeamScheduling` objects. You can get the `TeamScheduling` objects only by asking for `context.Schedulings.OfType<TeamScheduling>()`. Note that you cannot meaningfully use `context.Schedulings.OfType<Scheduling>()` to get the others: that will also include the `TeamScheduling` objects.

You could alternatively try `context.Set<TeamScheduling>()`, but I'm not entirely sure that will work.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to have two tables come up, say a parent Scheduling entity as well as a child TeamScheduling entity that has a foreign key back to the Scheduling entity, consider using a Table-per-Type (TPT) mapping as discussed [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx).

In essence, you should modify your "OnModelCreating" method to have the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TeamScheduling>().ToTable("TeamScheduling");
```

This explicitly tells EF that you want to have the TeamScheduling subclass to be represented as its own table. Querying it via LINQ would be simple as you would be able to do something like the following:

```
var teamScheds = context.Set<TeamScheduling>().Where(s => s.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```